# Is there a way to "tag" portions of Sprint item descriptions and build documentation from it?

Tags: jira

So, in the sprint item's Description, is there a way to enclose portions with some tags, like this:

$region 1.0 Name of Chapter 1

(Description goes here.)

$endregion

And then later be able to build a documentation dynamically from all the tags from different Sprint items?

Comment: From the comments, it's clear that the OP wants a tool recommendation, which is explicitly off-topic here on PMSE. With editing, help might be found on  Software Recommendations Stack Exchange.

Comment: You can create a [custom FreeTextField](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-display-a-field-based-on-another-field-s-selection-649921383.html) and have the information you need, which could fit your needs. However, as CG mentions, I believe this question is a better fit in another community - I expanded my thoughts on this [HERE](http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/a/792/430) on meta.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can, no. However, you might be able to get something similar by adding a custom (text) field, and putting it into *that* instead of into the Description.

Comment: Is there any plug in that might do this? Can't seem to find any in the JIRA portal. Though I am not sure I was searching with the right keywords. Seems like a common problem a lot would be facing, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

### Delimiters, APIs, and Project Sponsors

If you use good delimiters, you could use the [JIRA API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/) to parse [issues returned in JSON format](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue-getIssue), but the engineering-level details of how to do so are beyond the scope of a site about Project Management.

From a project management perspective, spinning up a project to have your software engineers write such a plugin might be something your company wants to spend resources on, or it may not. If your process genuinely needs such a tool, and nothing is available in the [Atlassian Marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/) that suits your needs, then finding a project sponsor for an internal initiative may be a reasonable next step for you *after* you exhaust your research efforts on what's already out there in the ecosystem.

Comment: Hi, yes, that's what I am trying to figure out - is there something like that in the Marketplace already - but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a forum even within Atlassian where I can reliably get an answer to this. I searched already and didn't find any, but want to ensure I don't reinvent the wheel.